How to create css grid where certain amount of columns always take half of grid
I have CSS Grid which has 7 columns and multiple rows. Is it possible to have first 4 columns occupying same width as last 3 columns when column width is dynamic?
In example below, I explicitly set grid-template-columns to specific widths to reproduce final result I want, but in real case scenario, I need to have dynamic width columns and grid, but first 4 columns should always be equal width to other 3 columns.


.grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 720px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 3fr) repeat(3, 4fr);
  >div {
    border: 1px solid gray;
  }
  .expl1 {
    grid-column: 1/span 4;
  }
  .expl2 {
    grid-column: 5/-1;
  }
}
<div class="grid">
  <div>Col 1</div>
  <div>Col 2</div>
  <div>Col 3</div>
  <div>Col 4</div>
  <div>Col 5</div>
  <div>Col </div>
  <div>Col 7</div>
  <div class="expl1">Above width is 4 * 90px = 360px</div>
  <div class="expl2">Above width is 3 * 120px = 360px</div>
</div>



Is there any solution without splitting grid into two columns and putting subgrid of 4 columns into first column and subgrid of 3 columns into second column?
Edit for clarification: The thing is that every column is dynamic depending on content. For example first 3 columns content: 50px 120px 30px makes 200px, rest 4 columns content 40px 150px 200px 50px makes 440px. We can see that first three columns lack 240px to be equal, so I want them to grow those 240px/3 = 80px each. So in the end each column min-width is content width, actual width whatever it takes to add up to be 50% of total grid width. The biggest issue that I can not know column widths in advance.

Yes, you can achieve this without splitting the grid into two columns or using subgrids. The key is to use fractional units (fr) in the grid-template-columns property while ensuring that the sum of the fractions for the first four columns is equal to the sum of the fractions for the last three columns.


.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr) repeat(3, 4/3fr);
}

.grid > div {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.expl1 {
  grid-column: 1 / span 4;
}

.expl2 {
  grid-column: 5 / -1;
}
<div class="grid">
  <div>Col 1</div>
  <div>Col 2</div>
  <div>Col 3</div>
  <div>Col 4</div>
  <div>Col 5</div>
  <div>Col 6</div>
  <div>Col 7</div>
  <div class="expl1">Above width is 4 * 1fr</div>
  <div class="expl2">Above width is 3 * 4/3fr</div>
</div>




The thing is that every column is dynamic depending on content. For example first 3 columns content: 50px 120px 30px makes 200px, rest 4 columns content 40px 150px 200px 50px makes 440px. We can see that first three columns lack 240px to be equal, so I want them to grow those 240px/3 = 80px each. So in the end each column min-width is content width, actual width whatever it takes to add up to be 50% of total grid width. The biggest issue that I can not know column widths in advance.

can't we use CSS Grid’s minmax() function combined with fr units?

Thanks. It seems repeat(4, minmax(auto, 3fr) repeat(3, minmax(auto, 4fr) almost gives what I need, except I need to set min-width: max-content to ensure it is not resized when content of all cells doesn't fit to view. Not sure if it is correct setting as it could force content of each cell to bet max-content width (need to test is this is the case).

Sure but don't use repeat


.grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 720px;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 3fr 3fr 3fr 4fr 4fr 4fr;
  >div {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    grid-column-end: span 1;
  }
  .expl1 {
    grid-column: 1 / span 4;
  }
  .expl2 {
    grid-column: 5/-1;
  }
}
<div class="grid">
  <div>Col 1</div>
  <div>Col 2</div>
  <div>Col 3</div>
  <div>Col 4</div>
  <div>Col 5</div>
  <div>Col </div>
  <div>Col 7</div>
  <div class="expl1">Above width is 4 * 90px = 360px</div>
  <div class="expl2">Above width is 3 * 120px = 360px</div>
</div>




The thing is that every column is dynamic depending on content. For example first 3 columns content: 50px 120px 30px makes 200px, rest 4 columns content 40px 150px 200px 50px makes 440px. We can see that first three columns lack 240px to be equal, so I want them to grow those 240px/3 = 80px each. So in the end each column min-width is content width, actual width whatever it takes to add up to be 50% of total grid width. The biggest issue that I can not know column widths in advance.

Then CSS Grid is not what you want. I'm doubtful this can be resolved without JS. Honestly this sounds like an XY problem, I'm confused as to a use case here.

Rewriting some code to new framework and found one block that needs to be split in half, where one block corresponds to purchase other to sell info and it is required for those block to be equal widths...However each block has different amount of columns depending on information required to display. I am thinkin about table solution in this case, but probably I will try to have some hardcoded widths in first place.
